# Using SPI,UART and I2C interfaces of the GPIO for other general purposes

Tags: gpio

Can I use the pins on the P1 connector that are reserved for SPI, UART and I2C for general purpose input/output instead? Can these pins be programmed for input/output like the other 8 non-reserved IO pins of the P1 connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, any of the GPIO pins except the 5v, 3v3 and Ground (GND) can be used as general purpose I/O pins in software.

The only thing to be aware of is any expansion boards that need the SPI / I2C / UART will need those particular pins to be set to the correct mode.